# Solving the Damped Harmonic Oscillator ODE as a first order system using midpoint methods

Tags: matlab

The exact solution of the damped harmonic oscillator

$$x'' + 2\gamma x' + \omega^2 x = 0, \quad x(0)=x_0, \quad x'(0)=-\gamma x_0$$

with $0 < \gamma < \omega$ is

$$x(t)= x_0 e^{-\gamma t} \cos(\beta t) \quad \text{where} \quad \beta:=\sqrt{\omega^2 - \gamma^2}$$

Notice that this second order ODE can be written as a first order system by making the substitutions:

$x' = y$ and,

$y' = -2\gamma y - \omega^2 x$

I want to solve the system using the method:

$$\dfrac{ x_{n+1} - x_{n-1} }{2h} = y_n \quad \quad \dfrac{y_{n+1} - y_{n-1}}{2h} = -2\gamma y_n - \omega^2 x_n.$$

which is an explicit midpoint rule. This is the code that I constructed for the problem, but it is not giving me the correct result. My plot has no harmonic behavior as I would anticipate.

```
function resonance

omega = 1;      % resonant frequency = sqrt(k/m)
a = 0.2;        % drag coeficient per unit mass
b = 0.1;        % driving amplitude per unit mass
omega0 = 1.2;   % driving frequency

tBegin = 0;     % time begin
tEnd = 80;      % time end

x0 = 0.2;       % initial position
v0 = 0.8;       % initial velocity

a = omega^2;    % calculate a coeficient from resonant frequency

% Use Runge-Kutta 45 integrator to solve the ODE
[t,w] = ode45(@derivatives, [tBegin tEnd], [x0 v0]);
x = w(:,1);     % extract positions from first column of w matrix
v = w(:,2);     % extract velocities from second column of w matrix

plot(t,x);

title('Damped, Driven Harmonic Oscillator');
ylabel('position (m)');
xlabel('time (s)');


% Function defining derivatives dx/dt and dv/dt
% uses the parameters a, b, A, omega0 in main program but changeth them not
function derivs = derivatives(tf,wf)
    xf = wf(1);            % wf(1) stores x
    vf = wf(2);            % wf(2) stores v
    dxdt = vf;                                     % set dx/dt = velocity
    dvdt = xf + 2 * b * vf + a * tf;  % set dv/dt = acceleration
    derivs = [dxdt; dvdt];  % return the derivatives
end

end
```

Also, my apologies about the formatting. I am use to math stackexchange, and the LaTeX style formatting doesn't seem to be applicable here and I do not know how to put my math in the math environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a sign, it should be

```
    dvdt = - ( xf + 2 * b * vf + a * tf );  % set dv/dt = acceleration
```

However, the whole expression is at odds with the previously stated equation,

```
x'' + 2*b*x' * a*x = 0
```

should result in

```
    dvdt = - ( 2*b*vf + a*xf );  % set dv/dt = acceleration
```

But then again you have defined `a` twice, so change `w2=omega^2` to get

```
    dvdt = - ( 2*b*vf + w2*xf + a );  % set dv/dt = acceleration
```